# Select Max Versions value

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to extract data based on a certain version of a given record. I want to extract the max version based on the final save of the first user for an ID. Is this possible?
--In my mock up I have version numbers as 1,2,3 but the numbers are actually randomly assigned in my database.

I am trying to use:

```
select id, max(version) over partition by id 
from t1
```

here is my data:
T1

```
ID    User   Version  
1     123      1  
1     123      2  
1     123      3  
1     456      4  
1     456      5  
1     789      6  
2     452      1  
2     452      2  
2     587      3  
2     123      4  
3     901      1  
3     767      2  
3     456      3
```

here is what I am trying to extract:
T1

```
ID    User   MaxVersion  
1     123      3  
2     452      2  
3     901      1
```

Comment: Suppose for ID = 1 you had User = 123 for Version 1, 2, 3 and then again for Version 7. (Not present in your sample data, but suppose you had one more row: ID = 1, user = 123, Version = 7). In that case, what Version do you need to select: 3 or 7? Do you care that the rows for that user are NOT CONSECUTIVE?

Comment: that would not be the case, but if it is, I would still need 3 as my requirement is to select the "first final version", every save by the user is a new version, and I'm looking for the final save of the first user who edited the record.

Comment: OK - then Gordon's solution won't help, you need an extra layer to identify CONSECUTIVE rows with that id. Not an issue if "that can't happen" but you need to be 100% sure about that (now as well as in the future!) In any case, the solution I offered does what you need, but it requires Oracle 12.1 or higher. What is your Oracle version? Run `select * from v$version` if you don't know for sure, and share the full version number (such as 11.2.0.4.0 or 12.1.0.2.0).

Comment: doesn't look like it is- 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: Have you provided ALL columns of the source table? What is the primary key?  Any date or timestamps? Reliance on the sequence of row storage isn't reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t1.*
from (select id,
             row_number() over (partition by id, user order by version desc) as seqnum,
             max(user) keep (dense_rank first order by version) over (partition by id) as first_user
       from t1
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1 and user = first_user;
```

You need to look for the user and the last record separately.

EDIT:

If you need the "first" final version, I would go with:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             min(case when user <> first_user then version end) over (partition by id) as last_version_plus_1
      from (select id,
                   max(user) keep (dense_rank first order by version) over (partition by id) as first_user
             from t1
           ) t1
      where seqnum = 1 and user = first_user
     ) t1
where version < max_version;
```

Or, you can do this with correlated subqueries:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where t1.user = (select min(tt1.user) keep (dense_rank first order by tt1.version)
                 from t1 tt1
                 where tt1.id = t1.id
                ) and
      t1.version < (select min(tt1.version)
                    from t1 tt1
                    where tt1.id = t1.id and tt1.user <> t1.user
                   );
```

This is the "old-fashioned" approach (pre-analytic functions).  But it captures exactly the idea.  The first makes sure the user is the first user.  The second makes sure the version is from the first records for that user.

Comment: Thank you! I have a couple of questions, since I need to go by the first user, shouldnt the partition order be version asc? And max(user) - I do not want to do a max on the user as the user id may not be in a certain order.

Comment: When you partition by `id` **and** `user` (to get the **highest** version number), you need to order by version descending, assign row numbers, and select row number = 1. Then, `max(user)` is an illusion; you keep `dense_rank FIRST order by version` and since `version` is unique within an `id`, the `max(user)` is the **only** user for that version. I believe the query is 100% correct, with one caveat - see question under your original post.

Comment: Im unable to run this query, I get an error - 'user' invalid identifier.

Comment: @skn . . . `user` is a reserved word in Oracle, but it is the name of the column in your question.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 12.1 and above, `match_recognize` can do quick work of such requirements. (One benefit, compared to analytic functions solutions, is that the `max(version)` is calculated for just one user for each `ID`, without requiring a subquery to achieve this efficiency).

The `match_recognize` clause partitions by `id` and within each `id` it orders by version (ascending). Then a "match" is from the start of the partition only (`^` in the `pattern` clause), and consists only of rows that have the same `id` as the first row (in that partition by `id`). All other rows for that `id` are ignored. Then the last version value is collected for the output.

NOTE: This assumes that, if for a given ID, the first user changes to a second, a third etc. but then reverts to the **first** user, the highest version number from the **FIRST** set of rows for that user is required. If instead the highest version number from ALL rows for that user is required, the query can be changed accordingly (specifically the PATTERN clause needs a change).

```
with
  inputs ( id, usr, ver ) as (  
    select 1, 123, 1 from dual union all  
    select 1, 123, 2 from dual union all  
    select 1, 123, 3 from dual union all
    select 1, 456, 4 from dual union all
    select 1, 456, 5 from dual union all
    select 1, 789, 6 from dual union all
    select 2, 452, 1 from dual union all
    select 2, 452, 2 from dual union all
    select 2, 587, 3 from dual union all
    select 2, 123, 4 from dual union all
    select 3, 901, 1 from dual union all
    select 3, 767, 2 from dual union all
    select 3, 456, 3 from dual
  )
-- End of simulated inputs (not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select id, usr, ver
from   inputs
match_recognize (
  partition by id
  order by ver
  measures last(usr) as usr,
           last(ver) as ver
  pattern ( ^ a+ )
  define  a as usr = first(usr)
);

ID  USR  VER
--  ---  ---
 1  123    3
 2  452    2
 3  901    1
```

**EDIT**:

For completeness, here is what the PATTERN should look like if a user may appear over non-consecutive rows, and the very last occurrence of that user (even if non-consecutive) for a given `id` must be considered:

```
...
    pattern ( ^ a (x* a)? )
...
```

Here the first row in the partition is an **a**, and if the same user appears again for the same `id` there is at least one more **a** row; the *last* such row is caught by the optional part of the pattern, with the greedy match on `x*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select rnk,id, user,mv from (select rownum as rnk,id,user,max(version) from T1

group by id, user )where rnk=1;
```